# Show that $A=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \Bbb R^2:\max(x_1,x_2)<5\}$ is an open set.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm not sure if the last part is ok. Can you check my proof, please? Any observation wi'll be very valuable.

Let $A=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \Bbb R^2:\max(x_1,x_2)<5\}$, then show that $A$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^2$

So we want to show that $\forall y\in A (y\in \Bbb R^2), \exists \varepsilon_y\gt 0: B(y,\varepsilon_y)\subseteq A$

We know that for $y=(y_1,y_2)\in A\Rightarrow \max(y_1,y_2)\lt 5$, now we define $\varepsilon=5-\max(y_1,y_2)\gt 0$ and so, $B(y,\varepsilon_y)=\{(w_1,w_2)\in \Bbb R^2:\lVert w-y\rVert\lt \varepsilon_y\}$

We'll show that $B(y,\varepsilon)\subseteq A$

Let $w\in B(y,\varepsilon)$ and so $\lVert w-y\rVert\lt \varepsilon$

If we assume from $\max(w_1,w_2)$ (without loss of generality) that $w_1\ge w_2$:

$$\sqrt{(w_1-y_1)^2+(w_2-y_2)^2}\le \sqrt{(w_1-y_1)^2}+\sqrt{(w_2-y_2)^2}=\lvert w_1-y_1\rvert + \lvert w_2-y_2\rvert\lt \varepsilon$$

And because $y$ is such that $\max(y_1,y_2)\lt \varepsilon$:
$$\sqrt{(w_1-y_1)^2+(w_2-y_2)^2}\le 2\lvert w_1-y_1\rvert \lt \varepsilon=5-\max(y_1,y_2)$$
$$\sqrt{(w_1-y_1)^2+(w_2-y_2)^2}\le \lvert w_1-y_1\rvert + \max(y_1,y_2)\lt 5$$
$$\sqrt{(w_1-y_1)^2+(w_2-y_2)^2}=\lVert w-y\rVert \lt 5$$

So, for any $w\in B(y,\varepsilon)$ is true that $\max(w_1,w_2)\lt 5$ and therefore $B(y,\varepsilon)\subseteq A$ and for that, $A$ is open set.

Comment: I'm not following the meat of your argument. Assuming $w \in B(y, \varepsilon)$ is a good idea, and certainly you want to conclude $\max(w_1, w_2) < 5$, but I don't really follow how the steps in between take you from one to the other. I even think the choice of $\varepsilon$ is correct! Try showing that $w_1 < 5$, to begin with. Hint: use $|w_1 - y_1| \le \|w - y\| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: "And because $y$ is such that $\max \{y_1, y_2\} < \varepsilon$" - this is not true. Take $y = 2 \times 3 \in A$ for instance; you have $\varepsilon = 5 - 3 = 2$, but clearly $\max \{ y_1, y_2 \} = 3$, which is not less than $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You generally have the right idea, but the last part of your proof is indeed somewhat unclear (at least to me).

To show $A$ is open, you've picked an arbitrary $y \in A$ (which implies $y_1, y_2 < 5$) and assert that $B_d (y, \varepsilon) \subseteq A$, where $d$ is taken to be the Euclidean metric, and $\varepsilon = 5 - \max \{y_1, y_2\} > 0$. That much makes sense.

To show $B_d (y, \varepsilon) \subseteq A$, you've selected an arbitrary $w \in B_d (y, \varepsilon)$ and seek to show that $w \in A$. That's the right idea too. But I do not follow your next step. Really, it's enough to show that $w_1, w_2 < 5$. Since $w \in B_d (y, \varepsilon)$, then

$$d^2 (w, y) = (w_1 - y_1)^2 + (w_2 - y_2)^2 < \varepsilon^2$$

$$\implies (w_1 - y_1)^2 + (w_2 - y_2)^2 < (5 - \max \{y_1, y_2\})^2$$

Since $y_1, y_2 < 5$, the last inequality implies that both of the following are true:

$$\begin{cases}
\underbrace{(w_1 - y_1)^2} + (w_2 - y_2)^2 < (5 - y_1)^2 \\
(w_1 - y_1)^2 + \underbrace{(w_2 - y_2)^2} < (5 - y_2)^2
\end{cases}$$

Since all squared quantities are non-negative, the above inequalities imply

$$\begin{cases}
(w_1 - y_1)^2 < (5 - y_1)^2 \\
(w_2 - y_2)^2 < (5 - y_2)^2
\end{cases}$$

Finally, using $y_1, y_2 < 5$ gives $w_1, w_2 < 5$, implying that $w \in A$, as desired.